# WGET download last date file with specific name from url

Tags: wget

I want to download via wget one file with last date from url with specific name.
If i use the command above wget download 3 different files:

```
20200614-002-v5i32.exe
20200615-002-v5i32.exe
20200616-002-v5i32.exe

wget -m -nd -A "*002-v5i32.exe" https://definitions.symantec.com/defs/download/norton_antivirus/index.html
```

How to specifies to download only last version of file with this end name `"*002-v5i32.exe"` ?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: Possible alternative approach: [HTTPDirFS](https://github.com/fangfufu/httpdirfs). Mount, identify the right file as if the files were local, copy to a local filesystem, unmount. I haven't tested.

Comment: **Update:** I have tested. The site in question does not work with HTTPDirFS (because what the site returns is too fancy? because it uses absolute URLs for `href=`?). The tool works with [Debian CD Image Server](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/) (which returns simpler documents with relative paths for `href=`) and other sites that expose plain directory listing via HTTP, so it's not broken. Probably it works as designed, unfortunately it cannot help you.

Comment: I had some trouble understanding the information you want to "switch on" in your question.  Be aware that when you use a wild card/glob like `*` it is often expanded by the shell before the program sees it, few programs will do a wildcard/glob/regex match internally unless they specifically say they will.  What might work is to author your own program that chooses all the exact details in advance and then invokes wget on the exact url you want. I also wonder if the topic of web crawlers might be useful here.  Check the manual :) (its a big manual) `man wget`, and let us know if it can.

Comment: In that server (Symantec end point update definitions) are always last 3 versions of that definition. They update daily. I want download by some script only last one. The begin of file is date for example 20200614-002-v5i32.exe. I use *-002-v5i32 to help wget to download the file with containing that part of name. I don't need to use wget. Can be other application